# OnClient Click not working in IE but works in GChrome

Tags: javascript, asp.net

ASP.net Page

```
        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
            function show_confirm() {
                var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to Save this Transaction");
                if (r == true) {
                    $('#<%=btnConfirm.ClientID%>').click();
                }
                else {
                }
            }
        </script>

   <asp:Content ID="detailContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="mainContentPlaceholder"
    runat="server">   
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
                 CssClass="primary positive big button" OnClientClick="return show_confirm();return false"><span class="check icon"></span>Save Transaction</asp:LinkButton> 
            <asp:Button ID="btnConfirm" runat="server" Style="display: none;" onclick="btnConfirm_Click"/>
</content>
```

This will trigger btnConfirm click if the User click yes on the popup message box.

on page view Source on IE

```
<a onclick="return show_confirm();return false;" id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_LinkButton1" class="primary positive big button" href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$mainContentPlaceholder$LinkButton1','')">
<span class="check icon"></span>Save Transaction</a> 
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$mainContentPlaceholder$btnConfirm" value="" id="ctl00_mainContentPlaceholder_btnConfirm" style="display: none;" />
```

Thanks in Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`show_confirm()` function does not return a Boolean Value. It should return a value to work properly.

Why not do it simply like the following, it will do what you are looking for.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"
     CssClass="primary positive big button" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"
     OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to Save this Transaction');">
     <span class="check icon"></span>Save Transaction </asp:LinkButton>
```